# Grunt build - Add a static path for images

Tags: django, angularjs, gruntjs

It's a Django served application with the front end written in AngularJs. I use grunt to build the application. When it is served through Django, the images are broken. The reason is that the image paths miss the term 'static'. How do I specify in the Gruntfile to add the term static? Moreover, do I need to modify my CSS to hardcode the static folder name?

Comment: Where do you need to add the word `static`? Is it that you're trying to add it to all of your css files? Or... I dunno...

Comment: Since I'm serving it through Django, `static` should go before images. `static/images`.

Comment: Yes, but where? In your CSS files? Or are you trying to redirect any `/images/whatever.png` URL to `/static/images/whatever.png` ? I don't understand at what stage/level/etc you're trying to "add the term static".

Comment: Right, before the images. I think I may have to add it in the CSS files as well.

Comment: I don't think I'm phrasing my question correctly. And I'm not sure how else to say it. The word "static" has to be added, but you're not telling us WHERE you want it added... do you want it added to the CSS files dynamically? Do you want it added as a URL redirect? WHERE? Not what.

Comment: I want the folder to be added when the build is run. Also, it will be nice if you could tell me how to add it in the CSS file as well.

Comment: I see, so you want to create a new directory in the build process and place the `images` directory inside of that? I'll add an answer for that. Adding that text to the css file is more difficult and I don't know of a Grunt task to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after discussion in the comments it looks like what you need is a simple [copy task](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) to move the images into a `/static/images` directory for serving by Django. This is how you would do that:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  // ...
  copy: {
    images: {
      files: [
        {
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'current/path/to/images',
          src: ['**'],  // you could change this to only copy *.png or whatever
          dest: 'static/images'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  // ...
});
```

You also asked about adding the `/static/` text to all images in the CSS files, that would be much more difficult and I don't know of a task that would do just that, but it can be done with a custom task.

Comment: Thanks. Please let me try this.